# JEST Cannot find module 'typescript-cookie'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, vite

I'm trying to run some tests in a project that was created using VITE + TS, and I'm getting the following error:

[image: Run tests error]

The module **typescript-cookie** is the only one it's not being found. If remove this module all tests work fine!

My jest.config.ts

```
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  collectCoverageFrom: ['<rootDir>/src/**/*.{ts,tsx}'],
  coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/config/jest-setup.ts'],
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/(?!@element)/'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.[jt]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@hooks': ['<rootDir>/src/commons/hooks'],
    '@contexts': ['<rootDir>/src/commons/contexts'],
    '@commons': ['<rootDir>/src/commons'],
    '@mock': ['<rootDir>/src/commons/mock'],
    '@common/components': ['<rootDir>/src/commons/components'],
    '@enum': ['<rootDir>/src/commons/enum/'],
    '@interfaces': ['<rootDir>/src/commons/interfaces/'],
    '@utils': ['<rootDir>/src/commons/utils/'],
    '@mainRoutes': ['<rootDir>/src/router'],
    '@services': ['<rootDir>/src/commons/services'],
  },
};
```

vite.config.ts

````
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@hooks': '/src/commons/hooks',
      '@enum': '/src/commons/enum',
      '@mock': '/src/commons/mock',
      '@common/components': '/src/commons/components',
      '@services': '/src/commons/services',
      '@common': '/src/commons',
      '@contexts': '/src/commons/contexts',
      '@interfaces': '/src/commons/interfaces',
      '@utils': '/src/commons/utils',
      '@mainRoutes': '/src/router',
    },
  },
});
```
````

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing the same error in a project that was created with Create React App. Assuming it's an issue with the library, I filed a bug report.

https://github.com/carhartl/typescript-cookie/issues/110

Comment: Good! I saw they fixed it in the latest version of the lib: https://github.com/carhartl/typescript-cookie/releases/tag/v1.0.4

Thank you @Leonhardt

Comment: update the library didn't work for me!